I im having a problem in pygame with displaying the sky
I'm making a platformer game and I'm trying to create the world but the sky.png doesn't show up. I tried with other PNGs and it still doesn't work.
I inserted the location and coordinates but instead of it appearing it was just a black screen
Here's my code:
import sys

import pygame

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
       pygame.init()

       pygame.display.set_caption('Shadow samurai')
       self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))

       self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

       self.img = pygame.image.load('assets/sky.png') 

       self.img_pos = (160, 260)
       self.movement = [False, False]
    
    def run(self):   
         while True:
            self.screen.blit(self.img, self.img_pos)

            for event  in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 pygame.quit()
                 sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                   if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                      self.movement[0] = True
                   if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                      self.movement[1] = True   
         pygame.display.update()
         self.clock.tick(60)

Game().run()      


you probably need to put the pygame.display.update() and self.clock.tick(60) inside the while True loop. You indentation is very inconsistent, I'd suggest that this is the first thing you fix in your code.

You can use print(self.img) after self.img = pygame.image.load('assets/sky.png') to check, if it loaded correctly.

also try indenting pygame.quit() and sys.exit() correctly by four spaces or one tab

As described in the comments, this can be fixed by putting the display update line within the loop rather than outside of it. To keep your code clean and indentation consistent (as was also suggested in the comments), you can use Black or other automatic Python code formatters to do the work for you (you can even set Black as your default formatter in VS Code and activate format on save to really make it easy). Applying Black and moving the display update (and clock tick) lines inside the loop yields the following code, which displays the sky.png image (assuming that it exists in the directory used to load it):
import sys

import pygame


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        pygame.display.set_caption("Shadow samurai")
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.img = pygame.image.load("assets/sky.png")

        self.img_pos = (160, 260)
        self.movement = [False, False]

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.screen.blit(self.img, self.img_pos)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.movement[0] = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.movement[1] = True

            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)


Game().run()

